# JavaFX evenly split children

Tags: layout, javafx-2, javafx-8

How can I acheive an evenly split UI, as the Player boxes demonstrate in the following example:

[image: Desired UI]

I would model it as an HBox with 2 evenly sized VBoxes, but I can't get them to stretch to the same size in the HBox.

Comment: post some code of your tryings, then we can find the error!

Comment: @Tobi I can't figure out how to make them grow. Just placing 2 VBoxes in an HBox makes them stick to the left with minimal size.

Comment: Try to give them some Width Values hBox.setPrefWidth(400);vbox.setPrefWidth(hbox.getPrefWidth()/2)

Comment: @Tobi You suggest binding the widths to half the size? That would definitely work, but feels a bit forceful. Isn't there a solution using just containers?

Comment: I m not quite sure, but you can also do setPrefWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE) and they will take as much space as they can get

Comment: @Tobi In android I would create a LinearLayout with weight 1 for each child.

Comment: There is no LinearLayout where you can set the Weight in JavaFX, using PrefWidth is a common way to do that

Comment: @Tobi Then give an answer with binding the width to half and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Stretching VBoxes as two halves of single HBox works for me with `HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"` property set for both VBoxes:

```
<HBox>
  <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
    ...
  </VBox>
  <VBox HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
    ...
  </VBox>
</HBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your HBox a PrefWidth Value. Then you can bind the Widths of your VBoxes to the half of that Width

```
hBox.setPrefWidth(400);
vbox.setPrefWidth(hbox.getPrefWidth()/2);
```

You might wanna take a look at JavaFX Scene Builder. There you can Design your Layouts.
Just saw using a SplitPane would also work. There you can set the DividerPosition to 0.5 (so centered). Then you can put every kind of Panes inside you like.

Answer (score 0):

Place the two `VBox`s in a [`TilePane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) instead of an `HBox`.

Comment: They won't stretch with a TilePane either. They will just be of equal size.

Comment: Post some code. You probably need to make sure the `TilePane` itself fills the available space, but it's impossible to help unless you post code.